# Manchester 433MHz Nano to ATTiny85

Tags: arduino-nano, attiny, rf

My transmitter is a Nano, the receiver is a Tiny85.
I use a Logic Analyzer to check if stuff is moving, I can clearly see data coming in at the receiver.

The receiver does not 'decode' the data, `man.receiveComplete()` is never `True` so in the end nothing happens.

I think the problem may be the difference in clock speeds, there are some things I have tried. The Nano is sending every second, in the logic analyzer I can see this come in every second so he is 'right on time'.
But I am not so sure about the ATTiny85..

- ATTiny85
- Tiny Core
- 8MHz (burned bootloader 3x)

It is still to fast, counting to 3 is not working ok..

**Bootloader burning log**

```
    /home/thijs/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino8/bin/avrdude -C/home/thijs/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino8/etc/avrdude.conf -v -v -pattiny85 -cstk500v1 -P/dev/ttyUSB0 -b19200 -e -Uefuse:w:0xFF:m -Uhfuse:w:0xD7:m -Ulfuse:w:0xE2:m 

avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Dec 16 2016 at 12:32:01
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/home/thijs/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino8/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/thijs/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyUSB0
         Using Programmer              : stk500v1
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
         AVR Part                      : ATtiny85
         Chip Erase delay              : 400000 us
         PAGEL                         : P00
         BS2                           : P00
         RESET disposition             : possible i/o
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    12     4    0 no        512    4      0  4000  4500 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6    32    0 yes      8192   64    128 30000 30000 0xff 0xff
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : STK500
         Description     : Atmel STK500 Version 1.x firmware
         Hardware Version: 2
         Firmware Version: 1.18
         Topcard         : Unknown
         Vtarget         : 0.0 V
         Varef           : 0.0 V
         Oscillator      : Off
         SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude: PAGEL and BS2 signals not defined in the configuration file for part ATtiny85, using dummy values
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.05s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e930b (probably t85)
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: PAGEL and BS2 signals not defined in the configuration file for part ATtiny85, using dummy values
avrdude: reading input file "0xFF"
avrdude: writing efuse (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: 1 bytes of efuse written
avrdude: verifying efuse memory against 0xFF:
avrdude: load data efuse data from input file 0xFF:
avrdude: input file 0xFF contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip efuse data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1 bytes of efuse verified
avrdude: reading input file "0xD7"
avrdude: writing hfuse (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: 1 bytes of hfuse written
avrdude: verifying hfuse memory against 0xD7:
avrdude: load data hfuse data from input file 0xD7:
avrdude: input file 0xD7 contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip hfuse data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1 bytes of hfuse verified
avrdude: reading input file "0xE2"
avrdude: writing lfuse (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: 1 bytes of lfuse written
avrdude: verifying lfuse memory against 0xE2:
avrdude: load data lfuse data from input file 0xE2:
avrdude: input file 0xE2 contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip lfuse data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1 bytes of lfuse verified

avrdude done.  Thank you.

/home/thijs/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino8/bin/avrdude -C/home/thijs/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino8/etc/avrdude.conf -v -v -pattiny85 -cstk500v1 -P/dev/ttyUSB0 -b19200 

avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Dec 16 2016 at 12:32:01
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/home/thijs/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino8/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/thijs/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyUSB0
         Using Programmer              : stk500v1
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
         AVR Part                      : ATtiny85
         Chip Erase delay              : 400000 us
         PAGEL                         : P00
         BS2                           : P00
         RESET disposition             : possible i/o
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    12     4    0 no        512    4      0  4000  4500 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6    32    0 yes      8192   64    128 30000 30000 0xff 0xff
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : STK500
         Description     : Atmel STK500 Version 1.x firmware
         Hardware Version: 2
         Firmware Version: 1.18
         Topcard         : Unknown
         Vtarget         : 0.0 V
         Varef           : 0.0 V
         Oscillator      : Off
         SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude: PAGEL and BS2 signals not defined in the configuration file for part ATtiny85, using dummy values
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.04s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e930b (probably t85)

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

**high level**
[image: analyzer1]

**zoomed**
[image: analyzer2]

I have tried to use the Analyzer options for Manchester encoding in Saleae Logic but I do not know how to configure it right..

**Receiver Code**

```cpp
#include <Manchester.h>
#include <TinyWireM.h>                  // I2C Master lib for ATTinys which use USI
#include "LiquidCrystal_attiny.h"

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);

#define RX_PIN 1
uint8_t moo = 1;
#define BUFFER_SIZE 4
uint8_t buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

int curs = 0;

void setup() {
//  mySwitch.enableReceive(0);  // Receiver on interrupt 0 => that is pin #2
  delay(1000);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.home ();
  lcd.setCursor (0, 0);
  lcd.print("Start "); 
  man.setupReceive(RX_PIN, MAN_1200);
  man.beginReceiveArray(BUFFER_SIZE, buffer);
  count();
}

void loop() {
  if (man.receiveComplete()) {
    uint8_t receivedSize = 0;

    //do something with the data in 'buffer' here before you start receiving to the same buffer again
    receivedSize = buffer[0];
    for(uint8_t i=1; i<receivedSize; i++)
      Serial.write(buffer[i]);

//    pushtolcd(".");  
    lcd.print("."); 
    Serial.println();

    man.beginReceiveArray(BUFFER_SIZE, buffer);
    moo = ++moo % 2;
  }
}

void pushtolcd(String text) {
  lcd.home ();
  lcd.setCursor (0, curs);
  curs++;
  lcd.print(text); 
  delay(500);
}

void count() {
  for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    lcd.print(i); 
    delay(1000);
  }
};
```

**Sender code**

```cpp
#include <Manchester.h>

#define TX_PIN  5  //pin where your transmitter is connected
#define LED_PIN 13 //pin for blinking LED

uint8_t moo = 1; //last led status
uint8_t data[20] = {11, '1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, moo);
  man.workAround1MhzTinyCore(); //add this in order for transmitter to work with 1Mhz Attiny85/84
  man.setupTransmit(TX_PIN, MAN_1200);
}


uint8_t datalength=2;   //at least two data
void loop() 
{

  data[0] = datalength;

  man.transmitArray(datalength, data);
  moo = ++moo % 2;
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, moo);


  delay(800);
  datalength++;
  if(datalength>18) datalength=2;
}
```